# Installing box2d with vcpkg

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

when I try to `#include <box2d/box2d.h>` in vscode. I got this error:

```
fatal error: box2d/box2d.h: No such file or directory
#include <box2d/box2d.h>
```

even the vscode autocomplete the library when I include it
 
my vcpkg list `./vcpkg list`
`box2d:x64-linux                                    2019-12-31       An open source C++ engine for simulating rigid b...`
I also made the integration step`./vcpkg integrate install`
output:

```
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/mohamed/packman/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

am I missing a step while installing the library

Answer (score 0):

When installing the package `vcpkg install box2d` you should have CMake targets instruction. For example I have this:

```
The package box2d:x64-linux provides CMake targets:

find_package(unofficial-box2d CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::box2d::box2d)
```

You then need to update your `CMakeLists.txt` with those instructions and eventually replace `main` with the name of your target.